# Sound is gone after booting system in text mode

Tags: linux, audio, grub, console, x-server

I started using 
`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="text"` grub argument for my boots, and recently noticed that the sound is missing. I start GUI from terminal using `startx` command,

here's my **.xinitrc** file:

```
#!/bin/bash

awesome
```

`alsamixer` command gives this output:

```
`cannot open mixer: No such file or directory`
```

**Update**

My problem looks highly similar to [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/1004156) bug

Comment: You might install `aumix` ; it is a mixer usable on the console

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch you might not understood the problem, it's not the console, the GUI doesnt play sound.

Comment: Perhaps you need to load some kernel modules related to sound.

Answer (score 0):

It is common for the login code for the display manager to load and/or configure a number of modules for a number of services including sound when a user logs in.  Starting in text mode, and using startX to get start the graphical interface bypasses this setup.

Normally, there are text mode windows available using  key combinations.  This provides ready access to a (multiple) full screen text windows.

If you find the display manager requires too many resources for your equipment there are several light-weight display managers to choose from.

Comment: I'm under the same impression. Any idea how to start sound service manually?

Comment: @Benedictus It's been a long time since I used sound on a text only system.  I did install a command line mixer.  It should depend on or load the relevant devices.

Comment: what is a 'command line mixer' is this a thing?

Comment: @Benedictus A command line mixer is  a program which allows you to perform the mixing functions (change volume, mix/choose signals, etc.) from a command line.  `alsamixer` is one of the available command line mixers.

Comment: As you see in the post I am using alsamixer.